# How to get a text of elements in div tag having same class name

Tags: java, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

there are 38 div tags in my web application and i want to get the text present in each div tags.following is the code:-

> `<div class="w-100 dt pa2 f7">` //this is parent div class
>
> `<div class="bg-white-10">`//sub class
>
> `<div class="dib bg-dirty-green w-100">`//sublcass
>
> `<p class="pa2 ma0 fl f6">` // class from where i want to capture the text
>
> `<span class="v-mid">Mega Contest - 20</span> </p>` //this is the text which i want to capture.

I tried with following code:-

`WebElement wb = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]")); //CONTEST_TABLE`

`List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='pa2 ma0 fl f6']")); //NUMBER_OF_CONTEST`

```
    int rc=list.size();
    System.out.println(rc);
    for(int i=0;i<rc;i++)
    {
        WebElement Contest_Name= list.get(i).findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='pa2 ma0 fl f6']"));
        String name = Contest_Name.getText();
        System.out.println(name);
    }
```

> i am getting "Mega Contest - 20" 38 times...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to retrieve element in List Array, You can get it single time:

`//span[@class='v-mid']`  if span class has Unique name,

OR if its common class name you can use with following parameter of xpath condition: `//p[@class='pa2 ma0 fl f6']//following::span[@class='v-mid']`